# escape character not working in scp

Tags: 16.04, command-line, ssh, scp

I am trying to transfer some file through scp. But it is not working,

```
scp "vogo_psql_db\:2017-08-30T18\:00\:01.762662" "username@xx.xx.xx.xx:db-dump"
ssh: Could not resolve hostname vogo_psql_db\\: Name or service not known
```

The problem is I think that due to colons, it is taking `vogo_psql_db`  as hostname even though the escape chars have been used.

What should be done to solve this ?

Comment: Try prepending an absolute or relative path to the local filename e.g. `"./vogo_psql_db:2017-08-30T18:00:01.762662"`

Comment: yeah cool ! worked. Is there any answer to the above question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the manual page `man scp`:

```
File names may contain a user and host specification to indicate that the
file is to be copied to/from that host.  Local file names can be made
explicit using absolute or relative pathnames to avoid scp treating file
names containing ‘:’ as host specifiers.  Copies between two remote hosts
are also permitted.
```

So, you can prepend the local filename with an absolute path, or just the simple relative path `./` i.e.

```
scp "./vogo_psql_db:2017-08-30T18:00:01.762662" "username@xx.xx.xx.xx:db-dump"
```